# How to use API Routes in Laravel 5.3

Tags: api, laravel, laravel-5.3

In Laravel 5.3 API routes were moved into the api.php file. But how can I call a route in api.php file? I tried to create a route like this:

```
Route::get('/test',function(){
     return "ok"; 
});
```

I tried the following URLs but both returned the NotFoundHttpException exception:

- `http://localhost:8080/test/public/test`
- `http://localhost:8080/test/public/api/test`

How can I call this API route?

Comment: It is working: http://localhost/myproject/public/api/test

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You call it by

```
http://localhost:8080/api/test
                      ^^^
```

If you look in [`app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L74) you'd see that by default it sets the `api` prefix for API routes, which you can change of course if you want to.

```php
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to call that in laravel 5.4 ? The default api route: `Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
}); ` I tried localhost/app/api/user but did not work

Comment: @utdev You use exactly the same. Remove `app` segment from your URI. It should look along the lines of `localhost/api/user`

Answer (score 2):

routes/api.php

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return response('Test API', 200)
                  ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
});
```

Mapping is defined in service provider App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider

```
protected function mapApiRoutes(){
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['api', 'auth:api'],
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
}
```