# Laravel: api leads to NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I am trying to test out an API route in Laravel, however, I'm feeling like I haven't really configured my server as Laravel intends! In short, I'm working with the following folder structure

```
root folder
|
| - Other project
| - amazingErik
```

so, logically, I would try to address my API for the AmazingErik project by heading to the following URL:

```
http://localhost/amazingErik/api/posts
```

however, this results in a NotFoundHttpException. Accoarding to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540236/how-to-use-api-routes-in-laravel-5-3) I should be referring to the following address:

```
http://localhost/api/posts
```

However, this simply results in a 'Not found' message. This is what my api.php looks like:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('/posts', function(){
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

So, my intention is to navigate to `http://localhost/amazingErik/api/posts` and fetch the result 'Hello World'. However, currently I have no idea on how to rectify this behaviour. I have no other method by which I can address my API so far.

Comment: Check `php artisan route:list` to see what the route is listed as.

Comment: it is listed as `api/posts`, remarkably without an initial `/` like the landing page has.