# Laravel route is not working in API, returns page 404

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

In routes/api.php I have the following route:

```
Route::post('/session/storeValue', 'HomeController@storeValue');
```

And in controller I have AJAX function:

```
<script>

        function noviArtikal() {

  var data = { name: 'User');

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/session/storeValue',
    data: data,
    success: function() {
      console.log("Valueadded");
    }
  });

        };
</script>
```

But keep getting error page not found when sending AJAX call.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what route your browser is calling see in-network tab in debugger console

Comment: It is calling http://localhost/session/storeValue

Comment: Is there any redirect happening?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540236/how-to-use-api-routes-in-laravel-5-3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use API Routes in Laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540236/how-to-use-api-routes-in-laravel-5-3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is api.php, it automatically adds /api/ to your URL. Try /api/session/storeValue.

From docs:

> Routes defined in the routes/api.php file are nested within a route
>   group by the  RouteServiceProvider. Within this group, the /api URI
>   prefix is automatically applied so you do not need to manually apply
>   it to every route in the file. You may modify the prefix and other
>   route group options by modifying your RouteServiceProvider class.

**EDIT:**

add name:

`Route::post('/session/storeValue', 'HomeController@storeValue')->name('custom_name');`

Then modify your javascript:

`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/session/storeValue',
    data: data,`

to

`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '{{ route('custom_name')}}',
    data: data,`

**EDIT 2:**
And yes, don't send CSRF_TOKEN (check @Yur Gasparyan answer)

Comment: I tried that but then it calls localhost/appname/public/api/session/storeValue with error 404

Comment: did you use `url: {{ route('yourroutename') }}` ?

Comment: I'm just calling onclick="noviArtikal()" from button

Comment: then don't write url manually, but through route function. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes add name like it's mentioned here. And then use: `url: {{ route('yourroutename') }}`

Comment: But I'm not sure where to call that as I'm just calling js function with Ajax call

Comment: Check Edit section in my answer

Comment: Ok, I edited as you said, now I get internal error 500

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182715/discussion-between-aleksandrs-and-barba).

Answer (score 4):

For first you dont need to send `CSRF_TOKEN` to `api`. There is no sense to check `CSRF-TOKEN` because it is an api. Also to send request to api you need to add  `api` prefix manualy.

Comment: If I change to Route::post('api/session/storeValue', 'HomeController@storeValue'); and     url: 'api/session/storeValue', if you mean like that I get localhost/appname/public/api/session/storeValue called.

Comment: You dont need to change ` Route::post('session/storeValue', 'HomeController@storeValue')` to ` Route::post('api/session/storeValue', 'HomeController@storeValue')`. You need to move your routes in `routes/api.php`

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your route/web.php

```
Route::post('/session/storeValue', 'HomeController@storeValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

simply give any name to the route just like this:

`Route::post('/session/storeValue', 'HomeController@storeValue')->name('somename');`

and in your ajax call just change the url attribute to:
`url: '{{ route('somename')}}',`

Laravel attach /api to the api routes automatically through RouteServiceProvider and it is found is `/Providers` folder.

Also you don't need `csrf_token` when you are making an Api call.