# Laravel post request not working with postman

Tags: php, laravel-5, postman

I am new to laravel, the problem I have encountered is post request is not working with the postman. I have spent the whole day on this error but nothing worked. Maybe I am making a mistake somewhere. Your help will be appreciated.

I also have tried it by disabling the following code in Kernel.php

```
// \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
// \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
```

api.php

```
Route::post('country', 'Country\CountryController@countrySave');
```

Controller.php

```
 public function countrySave(Request $request){

    $country = CountryModel::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($country, 200);
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
```

Following is the error

`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. in file C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_tutorial\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php on line 256`

Comment: have you set the the necessary headers in POSTMAN?

Comment: weird, in my case I just comment out CSRF and everything works

Answer (score 0):

The routes in "api.php" are only used when the url is in the format "yoursite.com/api/yourRoute". See [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39540341/5937898).

Laravel is looking for a POST route in "web.php", where you only have the single GET route. You should look at modifying the URL to tell Laravel you want the "api.php" routes.

Comment: I am using correct root and formatting. Secondly I have post and get routes with different method names. get route working fine. Problem is with post route.